# Unable to render array of objects in adaptivecard as lineitems with adaptivecards-templating

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have invoice data as JSON with line items as an array of objects, i'm trying to render invoice data with **adaptivecards-templating** engine, able to render json object but unable to render array of objects as rows.

I'm passing data conext as `${lineAttributes}` but mbf I'm getting  datacontext as like this `"$data":"[object Object],[object Object]"` and passing

Comment: Not getting line items means? Could you please share card JSON? Also could you please explain your scenario in more detail

Comment: Are you still looking into it? could you please conform?

Comment: could you please update?

Comment: Hi @Nikitha-MSFT, sorry for late response, issue is fixed, actual problem is with I'm passing data context in parent level, after passing data context to child container it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Copying answer from comments:

To render array of objects in adaptive-card as line-items with adaptive-cards-Templating, Data should be passed to data context to child container not to parent level.